# Security in jupyter notebooks on AI-platform

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

We have a shared ai-platform jupyter notebook instance, is there anyway for each user to have their own directory that is not shared with the whole team?

Comment: Notebooks is not a multi-user platform. Is there any reason why you need to use 1 single instance vs multiple instances per user?

Comment: Have you looked into JupyterHub ?